# GUI Not working with custom AbstractTableModel. Errors "Unknown Source"

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I am currently creating, or more trying to create the GUI for my project. What I need to do now, is create a JTable that reads the data from a LinkedList. I have a custom TableAbstractModel for this.

```
public class StudentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

public static final String[] columnNames = { "ID", "First Name",
        "Last Name" };
private LinkedList<Student> data;

public StudentTableModel(LinkedList<Student> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnNames[column];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Student student = data.get(rowIndex);
    if (student == null) {
        return null;
    }
    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
        return student.getID();
    case 1:
        return student.getFirstname();
    case 2:
        return student.getLastname();
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Now I was trying to build a very basic layout consisting just of the table, and the appropriate JTextfields and JButtons to test if the table actually works.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

private JTextField StudentID;
private JTextField Firstname;
private JTextField Lastname;
private JTextField Group;
private JButton Add;
private static Database DB; // << Does this have to be static? Eclipse tells me it needs to be, but I am not sure.
private JTable StudentTable;

public GUI(Database DB) {
    super("Theatre Management");
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.DB = DB;
    LinkedList<Student> data = null;

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    StudentID = new JTextField("Enter Student ID", 10);
    Firstname = new JTextField("Enter First Name");
    Lastname = new JTextField("Enter Last Name");
    Group = new JTextField("Enter Group ID");
    Add = new JButton("Add Student");
    StudentTable = new JTable();
    StudentTable.setModel(new StudentTableModel(data));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(StudentTable);
    StudentTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    add(StudentTable);
    add(StudentID);
    add(Firstname);
    add(Lastname);
    add(Group);
    add(Add);
    add(scrollPane);

    addStudentEvent add = new addStudentEvent();
    Add.addActionListener(add);

}

public static void createAndShow() {
    GUI Database = new GUI(DB);
    Database.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Database.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI.createAndShow();

}

private class addStudentEvent implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int G = Integer.parseInt(Group.getText());
        int ID = Integer.parseInt(StudentID.getText());
        String First = Firstname.getText();
        String Last = Lastname.getText();

        DB.getGroup(G).addStudent(ID, First, Last);
        DB.addStudent(ID, First, Last);
    }

}
```

}

Now, the problem is, as soon as I try to run the GUI, I just get a whole bunch of errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at theatremanagement.StudentTableModel.getRowCount(StudentTableModel.java:29)
at javax.swing.JTable.getRowCount(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.createTableSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.FlowLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateUnconditionally(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at theatremanagement.GUI.createAndShow(GUI.java:59)
at theatremanagement.GUI.main(GUI.java:64)
```

I am really stuck right now and have no clue how to fix that. If anybody could show me what I am doing wrong, that would be great. On other thing, I have to LinkedList in my program, in different classes. How does the TableModel know which one I want? Do I need to add anything to the TableModel, to make the table automatically update as soon as a add or delete a student?

**Update:**

```
private JTable setStudentList(LinkedList<Student> Studentlist) {
    JTable StudentTable = new JTable();
    StudentTable.setModel(new StudentTableModel(Studentlist));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(StudentTable);
    StudentTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    return StudentTable;
```

Does this method work to create the table with the linked list? Would I then call for the method as

```
setStudentList(Studentlist);
```

If I initiliazed an empty LinkedList as such:

```
LinkedList<Student> StudentList = new LinkedList<Student>();
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LinkedList` is never initalised...

```
LinkedList<Student> data = null;
// ... ///
StudentTable.setModel(new StudentTableModel(data));
```

Meaning that when `getRowCount` is called, the `data` object is `null`, hence the `NullPointerException`

**Updated**

You have any number of options that you can use to pass a reference to main `LinkedList` into the UI, but it will come down to how your work flow works.

You could...

Pass the reference to the UI via it's constructor....

```
public GUI(Database DB, LinkedList<Student> students) {...}
```

You could...

Pass the `LinkedList` in via a method in you `GUI` class...

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {

    //...//

    public GUI(Database DB) {...}

    public void setStudent(LinkedList<Student> students) {
        StudentTable.setModel(new StudentTableModel(students));
    }
}
```

**Updated with example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class PassTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PassTable();
    }

    public PassTable() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private ExampleTable example;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            example = new ExampleTable();
            add(example);
            JButton add = new JButton("Add");
            add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    LinkedList<Person> people = new LinkedList<Person>();
                    people.add(new Person("A", "A", 1));
                    people.add(new Person("B", "B", 2));
                    people.add(new Person("C", "C", 3));
                    people.add(new Person("D", "D", 4));
                    example.setPeople(people);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class ExampleTable extends JPanel {

        private JTable table;

        public ExampleTable() {
            this(new LinkedList<Person>());
        }

        public ExampleTable(LinkedList<Person> people) {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            table = new JTable(new SampleTableModel(people));
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }

        public void setPeople(LinkedList<Person> people) {
            table.setModel(new SampleTableModel(people));
        }

    }

    public class SampleTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private LinkedList<Person> data;

        public SampleTableModel(LinkedList<Person> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            String name = "";
            switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    name = "First name";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    name = "Last name";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    name = "Age";
                    break;
            }
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Object value = null;
            Person person = data.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = person.getFirstName();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = person.getLastName();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value = person.getAge();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }

    }

    public class Person {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int age;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. So, how exactly do I initialise it? What would I set it to? I really don't know at the moment...

Comment: Well, I would imagine `LinkedList<Student> data = new LinkedList<Student>();` would be sufficient.

Comment: Forget it, I know what you mean, just a little tired ;D Thank you! Can you tell me anything to my other questions?

Comment: My problem is now, I can't see the table in the GUI.

Comment: Essentially, the table model will use what ever `LinkedList` you pass to it when you construct it.  If you want to change it later, I'd simply create a new `StudentTableModel` passing it the `LinkedList` you want to use and set that as the table's model

Comment: Okay. Because I have a LinkedList<Studentlist> and a LinkedList<Student> in my program, how do I tell it to use the LinkedList<Studentlist>? Because they are both the same type of linked list.

Comment: I would be appear to me the `Student` and `Studentlist` aren't the same type

Comment: sorry, what I meant is, I have two LinkedList<Student> called Students and Studentlist.

Comment: Basically, create a new `StudentTableModel` passing what ever `LinkedList` you want to use (ie `StudentTable.setModel(new StudentTableModel(Studentlist));`) and it will update automatically

Comment: okay, I had tried that, and it gave me an error? I'll check it again.

Comment: okay, no error now, but since I am initializing the list in the GUI class, isn't it a different one from the one in my other class? And could you tell me, why my table is basically invisible? Its just a tiny gray spot.

Comment: 1- Yes.  If you need, you could pass the `LinkedList` from you other class in as part of the GUI's initalisation, but that comes down to how your workflow works 2- This is because of the `FlowLayout`. Basically, you table has no size because it has no data.  I'd use a different layout manager (or compound layouts)

Comment: Okay, thanks. How do I do that? Yes, I will use a different layout, I am testing all that now.

Comment: @Nino post another question regarding LayoutManager's or google them (there are hundreds of tutorials). Comments are not meant to put extra-questions, only clarifications regarding the original question.

Comment: My question is how to pass the LinkedList from my other class. And that is related to my original question of tellin the table what linked list to use. I know how the other layouts work.

Comment: You have dozen of options with regards to passing the linked list in, but it comes down to how your work flow works. You could pas it in via a parameter in the constructor or pass it as a parameter to some other method you could use a singleton to access the linked list directly

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really help me, as I am not familiar with these options. How do I pass it in the constructor?

Comment: The same way you passed Database to it

Comment: Would that work: public GUI(Database DB, LinkedList<Student> Studentlist) ?

Comment: Thanks again, sorry for bothering you so long, but I am under a little time pressure, as this is a school project. At the moment I am trying to implement the setStudent method. I understand how it works, but my question is, how do I call it? I know i call setStudent( ); but what would I put into the brackets? Do I have to initialize another LinkedList in the GUI class and call the method with that?

Comment: I would initialise your table model with a empty LinkedList, just as you are doing now. Use the setStudent method to pass in your other LinkedList when your ready, this will replace the first linked list with the one you pass in to the set method

Comment: thank you. I understand what you are trying to say, but don't quite understand how it will work. I will show you what I have tried, maybe it makes sense ;) I will put it in the question